# Bitmap null pointer Exception

Tags: android-studio, bitmapimage, bitmapfactory, nexus6

I have function that pick a picture from camera or gallery but when I try to set on an ImageView it returns Null pointer on bitmap.getWidth(), I also try to use decodeStream instead decodeFile but I get errors in the path variable, how can I solve that? Im testing on a Nexus 6,  BTW my english is not good.

thanks in advance!

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        String path = "";

        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            path = getRealPathFromURI(mImageCaptureUri); //from Gallery

            if (path == null)
                path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath(); //from File Manager*/

            if (path != null)
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        } else {
            path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

        }
        final double viewWidthToBitmapWidthRatio = (double) mImageView.getWidth() / (double) bitmap.getWidth();
        mImageView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * viewWidthToBitmapWidthRatio);

        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

this is the log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/tmp_avatar_1450385165853.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual  method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have a Permissions problem with the image.

```
open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

If the image is being generated dynamically and then saved to a temporary storage, insure you have the right to read from that storage. Also, make sure the image is readable when being saved / generated.

Also check to insure that your Activity has permission to access data from the camera

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

One last thing to consider, is using the 'takePicture' method from API Level1.
[Here is the takePicture documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture(android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback))

This returns the JPEG data to the callback, which may bypass the encoding step you're taking due to loading raw bytes from the file URI.

Comment: Thanks @Decoded4620 the error was that I should give permissions to use storage and GPS inside the app (I think this is new in Android marshmallow)

Comment: Its the little things that make life fun, isn't it!? ;)